# Conditional replace in a single Java regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I have some symbols in the form of alpha-numeric chars, followed by a single digit. The digit is a year and I need to expand to a two digit year, with 9 becoming 09 and any other year becoming prefixed with 1.

For example:

```
GCZ0 -> GCZ10
GCZ1 -> GCZ11
...
GCZ8 -> GCZ18
GCZ9 -> GCZ09
```

I am playing with `([A-Z]+)([9+])([0-9]+)` but I'm not sure how to get the replacement to conditionally include the right 0 or 1 prefix.

Could a regex master point me in the right direction please? For unfortunate reasons, I need to do this in a single Java regex match/replace.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Please show us the Java code so we can understand the "single Java regex match/replace" restriction.

Comment: Totally agree with Andrew, we need to know more.

Comment: Sadly it's part of a vendor product. It's a data import and it allows minimal 'customisation' by letting you apply a single regex transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, and no other answers here, I've concluded that this isn't possible in a single Java regexp.

Answer (score 7):

> For unfortunate reasons, I need to do this in a single Java regex match/replace.

Seems doubtful that such a solution exists... the conventional way would be to use [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and `Matcher.appendTail` to iterate through the source string, find pattern matches, perform arbitrary logic on them, and replace appropriate substitutions.

In Javascript you could use [a function with `String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) as a "smart replacement" rather than a fixed string.

Comment: Thanks. I added a comment above - it's part of a vendor product, the only API hook being a single regex transform on the field. So it looks like I might have to pre-process all the files instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : Oups, didn't read the single Regex Replace condition** ...

Well, never mind about what I suggested ...

Here is the Regex that matches exactly you need :

^[A-Z]{3}9$

Anyway, with a single Replace, I don't see how you could do it ...

I hope someone will be of better help than me.

**End Edit**

Using StringBuffer, you can insert a char :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("GCZ0");
if(sb.charAt(3) == '9') sb.insert(2, "0");
else sb.insert(2, "1");

String result = sb.toString();
```

In `result`, you have the right String you needed.

Comment: @khachik : I don't know if Jon is working with Java 5 or more, nor even if he's in a multi threaded environment or not, so I always go for StringBuffer in this sort of case :)